# Java school project random error

Tags: java, eclipse, random, system, project

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5iklxvhslh4kfe7/CS%203114.zip

There's some bug in my code for my school project that I just can't figure out. The link above is to my code for the project. The project instructions is in the P1.pdf file.

My error has something to do with this code:

```
                /*
                for (int i = 0; i < reactions.length; i++)
                {
                    reactions[i].UpdateFireTime();
                    debugwriter.write(i + "| " + reactions[i].FireTime());
                    debugwriter.newLine();
                }
                debugwriter.newLine();
                heap.build();
                //*/

                //*
                for (int i = 0; i < table[reactionIndex].length; i++)
                {
                    int rindex = table[reactionIndex][i];
                    reactions[rindex].UpdateFireTime();
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < reactions.length; i++)
                {
                    debugwriter.write(i + "| " + reactions[i].FireTime());
                    debugwriter.newLine();
                }
                debugwriter.newLine();
                heap.build();

                //*/
```

The first for loop updates the firing time of every reaction, while the second for loop uses my table to update specific dependent reactions. My answers are correct for the first for loop but incorrect when I use the second one. I've tested to see which propensities change if I update every reactions firing time and the results match my table. This means the only difference is the -Math.log(Math.random()) factor. If I set the random number to a constant, then I get the same results using both loops. I've looked over my code many times and I just can't figure out what the problem could be. Can anyone help me out?

P.S.:
The .ltf files are just .txt files that are quite large. I use the .ltf to distinguish them from regular .txt files

The correct means for the DIMER example are: ~650 ~650 ~220

EDIT: The third loop is just for debugging purposes. The 2 loops I'm talking about are the 1st and 2nd one where the 1st one is the one that's commented out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `table[reactionIndex]` in your first loop. Just use `table.length-1` and you can use `i` as your spot in the index to loop through and do stuff with.